# gulp + browserify transform configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify, brfs

I'm using gulp with browserify, how can I configure brfs-htmlmin? on npm page i find out I should pass options.minify object but how can I do that using browserify?

This doesn't work, any hints? (yes i'm new I installed node/npm yesterday;)

```js
gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.src('Components/initialize.js')
        .pipe(browserify({
            transform: ['brfs-htmlmin', { "opts": {minify: {removeComments: false}} }]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./buildjs'));
});
```

In the end i modified brfs-htmlmin source but there must be better way

brfs-htmlmin source:

```js
module.exports = function(file, opts) {
    if(/\.json$/.test(file)) return through();

    opts = opts || {};
    opts.minify = opts.minify || {
        removeComments: false,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true
    };
```

Comment: Are you using the gulp-browserify plugin? Its been deprecated. Use [this and other recipes to use browserify](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-uglify-sourcemap.md)

Comment: On top of what @Zasz suggested, there is some good explanation on why the deprecation of gulp-browserify happened here: https://medium.com/@sogko/gulp-browserify-the-gulp-y-way-bb359b3f9623

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not as convenient as putting the configuration on `gulpFile.js` you can put the configuration on `package.json`.

```
"//": "browserify transform config doesn't work if placed on gulpFile.js or karma.conf.js",
"browserify": {
    "debug": "true",
    "transform": ["brfs-htmlmin", { "opts": { "minify": {"removeComments": "false" }}}]
}
```